# UITableViewCell with custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a `UITableView` with a custom `UIButton` in each table cell. I implemented like this..

```
@implementation CouponDetailsCustomTableViewCell

          ...............

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;

        self.radioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_blank.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.radioButton setFrame:CGRectMake(16, 10, 29, 29)];
        [self.radioButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:radioButton];
}


@end
```

and UITableView Delegate as......

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *COUPON_CELL_ID = @"CouponCell" ;

    CouponDetailsCustomTableViewCell * couponCell = (CouponDetailsCustomTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:COUPON_CELL_ID];
    if (couponCell == nil) {
        couponCell = [[[CouponDetailsCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:COUPON_CELL_ID] autorelease];
        couponCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    [couponCell.radioButton setSelected:NO];
    return couponCell;
}
```

and the radioButtonPressed method is

```
-(void)radioButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
     [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

Now i run the program and a custom `UIButton` is shown in every table row . If i click on a button it gets selected (shows the `radio_selected.png`).

The problem arises when i scroll down the table (i am showing only 4 rows of the table in the window) . When i scroll up again..what i see is the clicked button is showing the `radio_blank.png`.

I am new in iPhone development. i dont know why is this happening. The most i can guess is the button property is changing ..  `setSelected:NO`.

Someone please give me suggestions to fix this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll your UITableView, hidden cells are not rendered anymore and might be reused for cells that are becoming visible. If a new cell becomes visible, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called.

The problem is that you're setting the **selected** state there:

```
[couponCell.radioButton setSelected:NO];
```

Therefore, whenever you scroll your cell out of the visible area and back again, it gets reset to `selected = NO`.

I suggest you create a `NSMutableDictionary` where you store the selection state of each row/NSIndexPath, which you then re-apply in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2):

replace `[couponCell.radioButton setSelected:NO];` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with code that sets the selected property depending on a state from your dataSource.

something along those lines:

```
/* get the button state from your data source */
FancyCouponObject *coupon = [self.coupons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL buttonState = coupon.buttonState;
[couponCell.radioButton setSelected:buttonState];
```

The cells of a tableView are reused when they are moved off screen. You can't save state in them.

Answer (score 1):

problem is when you scroll the table at that time your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method called for every row... so here when its called at time your `setSelected` Method call with NO argument like bellow...

[couponCell.radioButton setSelected:NO];

so when you scroll table at time your setSelected method call and your button turn with radio_blank.png 
...
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)radioButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
     [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

in this method you are setting button as selected and for selected button you have set the radio_blank.png image

Comment: [self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_blank.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: in your pressed button, i wrote code above. not here.  the button is in selected state and for selected sate your image is black